# Character Classes for find command using emacs regex style

Tags: regex, shell, emacs, find

For example, I want to find a file ends with `numbers`+`.bed`, it works if used this:

```
find . -regex ".*/[0-9]+\.bed"
```

As I know, **find** uses `emacs regex style` by default, so I found this page: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char-Classes.html#Char-Classes  and then try to use `[[:digit:]]` to replace `[0-9]`, but none of these commands works for me.

```
find . -regex ".*/[:digit:]\.bed"
```

Or

```
find . -regex ".*/[[:digit:]]\.bed"
```

Does anybody have any ideas about where I was wrong in the command?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a different regex type. For example, try:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/[[:digit:]]+\.bed"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the `find` documentation is out of date: the regexp syntax accepted by Emacs has changed over the years, but `find`'s apparently hasn't changed accordingly.